# Python, exit While loop with User Input using multithreading (cntrl+c wont work)

Tags: python, while-loop, parallel-processing, python-multithreading, keyboardinterrupt

I have a system utilization function, monitor(), that I want to run until the user stops it, by typing the number Zero, exit_collecting().  I don't want to abruptly end the program because that would negate the subsequent code.
I tried running the two functions using multithreading, exit_collecting() and monitor(), letting monitor() run until the user stops it by typing Zero, exit_collecting().

My code below threw a pile of tracebacks. I am a newbie at this, any ideas, any help would be great. Thank you. BTW I originally attempted using "try with an except for KeyboardInterrupt", but when using the IDLE (Spyder), the ctrl-c combo doesn't work (its assigned to "copy"), ctrl-c didn't work when I ran it from the console in Linux either.

```
def exit_collecting():
    try:
        val = int(input("Type 0 to exit data collection mode"))
        if val == 0:
            flag = 0
    except:
        print(val,"typo, enter 0 to exit data collection mode")


def monitor():
    import time
    import psutil
    flag = 1
    while flag > 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("cpu usuage:",psutil.cpu_percent())
        

from multiprocessing import Process
p1 = Process(target=exit_collecting)
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=monitor)    
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version with multiprocessing is doomed to failure since each process has its own memory space and does not share the same variable `flag`. It can be done with multiprocessing but you must use an implementation of `flag` that uses shared memory.

A solution using threading is far simpler and your code should work if only you make one change. You neglected to declare `flag` as global. This is required to ensure that functions `exit_collecting` and `monitor` are modifying the same variable. Without these declarations, each function is modifying a *local* `flag` variablle:

```
def exit_collecting():
    global flag
    try:
        val = int(input("Type 0 to exit data collection mode"))
        if val == 0:
            flag = 0
    except:
        print(val,"typo, enter 0 to exit data collection mode")


def monitor():
    global flag
    import time
    import psutil
    flag = 1
    while flag > 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("cpu usuage:",psutil.cpu_percent())


from threading import Thread
p1 = Thread(target=exit_collecting)
p1.start()
p2 = Thread(target=monitor)
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

But perhaps the above code can be simplified by making the `monitor` thread a *daemon* thread, that is a thread that it will automatically terminate when all non-daemon threads terminate (as currently written, it appears that function `monitor` can be terminated at any point in processing). But in any case, the main thread can perform the function that `exit_collecting` was performing. And there is no reason why you now can't use a keyboard interrupt (as long as you are waiting on an `input` statement in the main thread):

```
def monitor():
    import time
    import psutil
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("cpu usuage:",psutil.cpu_percent())


from threading import Thread
p = Thread(target=monitor)
p.daemon = True
p.start()
try:
    input("Input enter to halt (or ctrl-C) ...")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass         
"""
When the main thread finishes all non-daemon threads have completed
and therefore the monitor thread will terminate.
"""
```

**Update: Allow `monitor` thread to gracefully terminate and allow keyboard interrupt**

I have simplified the logic a but just to use a simple global flag, `terminate_flag`, initially `False`, that is only read by the `monitor` thread and therefore does not have to explicitly declare it as Global:

```
terminate_flag = False

def monitor():
    import time
    import psutil
    while not terminate_flag:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("cpu usuage:", psutil.cpu_percent())


from threading import Thread

p = Thread(target=monitor)
p.start()
try:
    input('Hit enter or ctrl-c to terminate ...')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
terminate_flag = True # tell monitor it is time to terminate
p.join() # wait for monitor to gracefully terminate
```

Comment: Thank you, especially for the clear wording.  The first solution worked well.  In my code there is some more reporting being done that is saved to a csv after the WHILE loop is closed.  That occurs smoothly with the first solution, but doesn't seem to happen with the second (not sure if its hanging).  One "working solution" for me is fantastic!

Comment: For clarification, is there something I can add so that when the WHILE loop is interrupted it finishes the block, before proceeding to the remaining code?

Comment: If you are terminating because you are a daemon thread and all non-daemon threads have terminated, then you have no control over your termination. So you have to use terminate by testing a `flag` value as in the first code example. But you can still get rid of the `exit_collecting` thread and have that logic performed in the main thread so that you can handle the ctrl-c keyboard interrupt.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarifications.   I tried to work it out using main thread and changing the flag in the try/except that followded, but I am pretty new to this, it didn't crash but didn't seem to work.  The first solution worked well and was east to follow, even for a newbie, tnx.

Comment: I've added a new version.

Comment: It it exits the while block midstream, so writing the results to file is breaking incomplete, I appreciate the education.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your last comment. `monitor` should not be interrupted. It will run until it finds that `terminate_flag` is `True` and then it will break from the while loop and return and the thread will terminate.

Comment: Sorry, I take that back, when I amended the code I must of hit something and apparently shifted a line of code out of block, it works well.  Thanks again for all the help.